# Use joblib to check whether an integer is a prime number or not. If it is, calculate its square; otherwise, append None to the returned value

Tags: python, joblib

```
import joblib

def is_prime(n):
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def square_if_prime(n):
    if is_prime(n):
        return n * n
    return None

primes = joblib.Parallel(n_jobs=4)(joblib.delayed(square_if_prime)(n) for n in range(2, 100000))
primes = [prime for prime in primes if prime]
print(primes[:10])
```

Comment: Welcome! Please edit to explain what your question is. As written, it's just a problem description (in the title) and then just code. Does your code work? Is there a specific issue? Please edit to include all relevant details (inputs, expected vs actual outputs, errors, etc)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```py
def is_prime(n):
    for i in range(2,int(n**0.5)+1):
        if n%i==0:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Please edit your question to explain your solution. Currently it's just code plus "try this." Further: the OP hasn't described any issue; they, too, just provided code. So it's unclear what, exactly, you're answering.